# Is it good practice to document.body every page?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am assuming that it is good practice to reduce the amount of document.querySelector, document.getElementById and so on (what is the proper term for this?). However, there are many different scripts running on every page of my website. That is why I would like to 'const body = document.body' every page. Is it a good idea?

In case, it is not totally clear what I mean, I am sure the following example will help:

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Practice A

```js
const header = document.querySelector('header');    
const nav = document.querySelector('nav'); 
const main = document.querySelector('main'); 
const footer = document.querySelector('footer');
```

Practice B

```js
const body = document.body;
const header = body.querySelector('header');
const nav = body.querySelector('nav');
const main = body.querySelector('main');
const footer = body.querySelector('footer');
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't think there's any measurable difference here (or any at all).

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization, and would barely help anyway (like 0.00001 ms of processing time, or something like that)

Comment: This is unlikely to have any practical measurable effect.

Comment: *"I am assuming that it is good practice to "* why do you assume that? And second: *"That is why I would like to 'const body = document.body' every page. Is it a good idea?"* so you're replacing 4 `querySelctor()` calls with 4 `querySelctor()` calls plus an additional global constant.  What's the benefit here, in your opinion?

Comment: @Thomas The benefit here would be from querying on a element with smaller scope (document.body is a child of document), so there definetly will be some gains there. Althrough unless it's looped/accessed hundreds/thousands of times it won't be any noticable gain.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is really minimal and I'd argue it's not worth the trouble, but Practice B is [ever-so-slightly faster](https://jsperf.com/stack-overflow-query-selector-answer) in my browser ([Brave](https://brave.com/) 0.66.61 Chromium: 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)).

Both tests (4 queries on each test) are running in about .000008 seconds (120,000 times per second), so unless you're doing this hundreds of thousands of times it's not going to make any difference.

[image: jsperf test]

Comment: I think it would depend on how many tags are outside of the body tag, so not sure how close that is to average html page

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can always assume that the less deep you're going into the DOM tree, less is the work JS has to do. Hence, if you're storing DOM node in a variable and then accessing its children from that node, it'll always be faster than doing it from the root node. However, since body is just the first level node, I don't think there would be significant performance boost unless you are doing hundreds of thousands of DOM queries and updates a second.

Hope that helps!